# On Page Load Hide Add new button of subgrid on form value in CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

I want to hide add new button of subgrid (Contact Entity) on page load (Account Entity). I have tried with following [link](https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/489288-show-or-hide-the-add-new-button-on-form-sub-grid), but its not working,

Below is the red button in image that i want to hide.

Please help me out.

[image: Example]

Comment: Hi Shahbaaz, Welcome to SO! In general it's better to paste a code snippet from the link you are referring to, instead of the link itself: this way if the site goes down, there is still a record of what you tried.

Comment: Hi keith, below is the code that i am using                                     function DisableSubGridNewButton() {
 
    var attribute = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('name').getValue();
    
    if (attribute == '' && attribute == "") 
        return true;  // show button
    else
        return false;  //hide button
}

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way of doing this

But we can do it with an unsupported way by using Jquery/JS.But Use legacy form rendering to "NO".unsupported Customizations won't work.

Check this in Crm 2016
Under Settings --->Administration --->System Settings ---->Use legacy form rendering to "NO"